# How can I solve this GitLab CI/CD Pipeline error for a simple C build?

Tags: c, continuous-integration, gitlab, pipeline

I am pretty new to C programming and also CI/CD. I have an assignment in which I got a C project and I have to build it using GitLab CI/CD.

After some research, I have written the following yaml file:

```
image: gcc

before_script:
    # Install build dependencies
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake

myapp:
    # Build the application
    stage: build
    script:
        - mkdir build
        - cd build
        - cmake ..
        - make
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:64 (MESSAGE):
  FATAL ERROR : Library not found - cryptopp.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  common/CMakeLists.txt:261 (check_library)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need to make the script install some more build dependencies. Maybe the libcrypto++-dev package?

Comment: `Library not found - cryptopp`  install the library

Comment: If you want to install `libcrypto++-dev`, you can modify your `before_script` to `- apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake libcrypto++-dev`.